# Number of bytes used for Unicode characters in varchar

Tags: sql-server, varchar, sqldatatypes, nvarchar

> A common misconception is to think that CHAR(n) and VARCHAR(n), the n defines the number of characters. But in CHAR(n) and VARCHAR(n) the n defines the string length in bytes (0-8,000). n never defines numbers of characters that can be stored

According to this statement from Microsoft, I assume, n is the data length of a string and when we store unicode characters in `varchar`, a single character should take 2 bytes. But, when I try with a sample as below, I see `varchar` data taking 1 byte instead of 2 bytes.

```
declare @varchar varchar(6), @nvarchar nvarchar(6)

set @varchar = 'Ø'

select @varchar as VarcharString, len(@varchar) as VarcharStringLength, DATALENGTH(@varchar) as VarcharStringDataLength
```

[image: Query Result]

Could someone explain the reason behind it?

Comment: `VARCHAR` does **NOT** store Unicode text - `NVARCHAR` does. `VARCHAR` is always as long as the number of characters stored in it - 1 byte per character stored.

Comment: OK. I mistook 'Ø' for 'ǿ'. When I try to set the variable value to 'ǿ', I see that varchar cannot store it and returns ? in result.

```declare @varchar varchar(6)
set @varchar = 'ǿ'

select @varchar as VarcharString, len(@varchar) as VarcharStringLength, DATALENGTH(@varchar) as VarcharStringDataLength ```

***Does nvarchar(1) means, it can store one unicode character of size 2 bytes?***

Comment: A variable of type `nvarchar(1)` can store **1** Unicode character, and it will use up **2 bytes** of space to do so

Answer (score 1):

Found time to test the assumptions of my first answer:

- Create UTF8-enabled database

`CREATE DATABASE [test-sc] COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_KS_SC_UTF8`

- Create table with all kinds of N/VARCHAR columns

`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UTF8Test](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [VarcharText] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI NULL,
    [VarcharTextSC] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_KS_SC NULL,
    [VarcharUTF8] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_KS_SC_UTF8 NULL,
    [NVarcharText] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_KS NULL,
    [NVarcharTextSC] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_KS_SC NULL,
    [NVarcharUTF8] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_KS_SC_UTF8 NULL)`

- Insert test data from various Unicode ranges

`INSERT INTO [dbo].[UTF8Test] ([VarcharText],[VarcharTextSC],[VarcharUTF8],[NVarcharText],[NVarcharTextSC],[NVarcharUTF8])
     VALUES ('a','a','a','a','a','a')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[UTF8Test] ([VarcharText],[VarcharTextSC],[VarcharUTF8],[NVarcharText],[NVarcharTextSC],[NVarcharUTF8])
     VALUES ('ö','ö','ö',N'ö',N'ö',N'ö')
-- U+56D7
INSERT INTO [dbo].[UTF8Test] ([VarcharText],[VarcharTextSC],[VarcharUTF8],[NVarcharText],[NVarcharTextSC],[NVarcharUTF8])
     VALUES (N'囗',N'囗',N'囗',N'囗',N'囗',N'囗')
-- U+2000B
INSERT INTO [dbo].[UTF8Test] ([VarcharText],[VarcharTextSC],[VarcharUTF8],[NVarcharText],[NVarcharTextSC],[NVarcharUTF8])
     VALUES (N'',N'',N'',N'',N'',N'')`

- SELECT lengths

`SELECT TOP (1000) [Id]
      ,[VarcharText]
      ,[VarcharTextSC]
      ,[VarcharUTF8]
      ,[NVarcharText]
      ,[NVarcharTextSC]
      ,[NVarcharUTF8]
  FROM [test-sc].[dbo].[UTF8Test]
SELECT TOP (1000) [Id]
      ,LEN([VarcharText]) VT
      ,LEN([VarcharTextSC]) VTSC
      ,LEN([VarcharUTF8]) VU
      ,LEN([NVarcharText]) NVT
      ,LEN([NVarcharTextSC]) NVTSC
      ,LEN([NVarcharUTF8]) NVU
  FROM [test-sc].[dbo].[UTF8Test]
SELECT TOP (1000) [Id]
      ,DATALENGTH([VarcharText]) VT
      ,DATALENGTH([VarcharTextSC]) VTSC
      ,DATALENGTH([VarcharUTF8]) VU
      ,DATALENGTH([NVarcharText]) NVT
      ,DATALENGTH([NVarcharTextSC]) NVTSC
      ,DATALENGTH([NVarcharUTF8]) NVU
  FROM [test-sc].[dbo].[UTF8Test]`

[image: SELECT lengths]

I was surprised to find that the old mantra "a `VARCHAR` only stores single byte characters" needs to be revised when using UTF8 collations.

- Note that only table columns are associated with collations, but not T-SQL variables:

`SELECT @VarcharText = [VarcharText],
    @NVarcharText = [NVarcharText]
  FROM [test-sc].[dbo].[UTF8Test]
   WHERE [Id] = 4
SELECT @VarcharText, Len(@VarcharText), DATALENGTH(@VarcharText), @NVarcharText, Len(@NVarcharText), DATALENGTH(@NVarcharText)
SELECT @VarcharText = [VarcharTextSC],
    @NVarcharText = [NVarcharTextSC]
  FROM [test-sc].[dbo].[UTF8Test]
   WHERE [Id] = 4
SELECT @VarcharText, Len(@VarcharText), DATALENGTH(@VarcharText), @NVarcharText, Len(@NVarcharText), DATALENGTH(@NVarcharText)
SELECT @VarcharText = [VarcharUTF8],
    @NVarcharText = [NVarcharUTF8]
  FROM [test-sc].[dbo].[UTF8Test]
   WHERE [Id] = 4
SELECT @VarcharText, Len(@VarcharText), DATALENGTH(@VarcharText), @NVarcharText, Len(@NVarcharText), DATALENGTH(@NVarcharText)`

[image: SELECT @Variable lengths]

Comment: This clears up lot of questions I have on varchar, nvarchar and encoding. Thank you for the details. I am preparing for 70-761 certification. Any suggestions for preparation material?

Comment: sorry, can't help you with certification

Answer (score 0):

I thought the [original quote](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql) was a bit confusion, as it continues

> The misconception happens because when using single-byte encoding, the
>   storage size of CHAR and VARCHAR is n bytes and the number of
>   characters is also n.

but since it mentions *encodings*, my guess is that the statement refers to the  [UTF encodings supported in SQL Server 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support) and higher which seem to allow (I haven't tried yet) to store Unicode in `VARCHAR` columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @char varchar(4)
declare @nvarchar nvarchar(4)

Set @char = '@'
Set @nvarchar = '@'

select @char as charString, 
LEN(@char) as charStringLength,
DATALENGTH(@char) as charStringDataLength

select @nvarchar as nvarcharString, 
LEN(@nvarchar) as nvarcharStringLength,
DATALENGTH(@nvarchar) as nvarcharStringDataLength
```

Comment: Try to run my code in SSMS and check datatype i think you wll get solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can store unicode in varchar (if you want to), however every byte is interpreted as a single character, while unicode (for sql server, utf16, ucs2) uses 2 bytes for a single character and you have to account for that, when displaying unicode stored in varchar.

```
declare @nv nvarchar(10) = N'❤'
select @nv;

declare @v varchar(10) = cast(cast(@nv as varbinary(10)) as varchar(10))
select @v, len(@v); --two chars

select cast(@nv as varbinary(10)), cast(@v as varbinary(10)); --same bytes in both n/var char
--display nchar from char
select cast(cast(@v as varbinary(10)) as nvarchar(10));
```

Comment: From the statement ``` declare @v varchar(10) = cast(cast(@nv as varbinary(10)) as varchar(10))
select @v, len(@v); --two chars ```

Though it appears to store the data, it won't be able to reproduce the same with select. the result is 'd''. However the size is 2 bytes.

Comment: `declare @v varchar(10) = cast(cast(N'A' as varbinary(10)) as varchar(10))
select @v, len(@v), '*'+@v+'*'; --two chars(where did the 2nd * go?)`